# The correct Kali Gayatri mantra

Tags: scripture, mantras, tantra, kali, gayatri-mantra

Does anyone know the difference between these 3 Kali Gayatri mantras?

The First one:

om pishachadwajayai vidmahay

shoolahasthaya dhimahi

tanno kali prachodayat

Second:

oṃ mahākālyai ca vidmahe

śmāśāna vāsinyai ca dhīmahi

tanno kālī pracodayāt

Third:

oṃ kālikayai ca vidmahe

śmāśāna vāsinyai ca dhīmahi

tanno Aghora pracodayāt

Do they have different effects? Can they be found in any of the scriptures?

Comment: All of those can be correct. A deity usually have more than one Gayatri Mantra dedicated to it. Usually different scriptures contain them that's why different Mantras.